# Best way to exit a program gracefully without using pkill

Tags: c++, linux

I am currently using a script to call `pkill` to terminate my C++ program.
However i noticed that the destructors were not called from my traces when using pkill.

Is there another good way that i can exit the program gracefully?
`pkill` seems kind of untidy and some logs in the buffer do not get recorded. I'd like to be able to flush on my fstream and to close all resources programatically (instead of relying on the O/S to clean up my mess).

The application runs 24/7 without any problem, the only time i want to stop it is during maintenance. The application does not have any user interface for me to type exit.

Comment: What kind of application is it?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, it is a production application that receives commands from another system to perform some calculations and monitoring. i should have mentioned that any changes needs to be fully tested before it enters production.

Comment: Then it very probably has already some event loop.... So adding a controlling pipe could be simpler.... See also my reply ...

Comment: You should move to not use pkill - because its argument is taken as a regex which can lead to signalling more processes than you intended. (Alternatives: e.g. LSB killproc with pid files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it by defining a signal handler for `SIGTERM` along these lines:

Somewhere in your include block:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Yes, we're doing i `C` style!

Somewhere in the initialization part of your code:

```
signal (SIGTERM, handler);
```

and then define the signal handlers code (flush everything, etc):

```
void handler(int num) 
{
  // we might use this handler for many signals
  switch (num)
  {
    case SIGTERM:
      // clean up code.
      break;
  }
}
```

Now when you run `pkill <app>`, where `<app>` is the name of the executable, the code for `handler()` will run.

Without switches, the default `SIGTERM` signal will be sent to the application. Should you choose to use a different signal you would have to make sure you send the same signal as you "catch" in the `handler()`.

Relevant information can be found by `man 7 signal` and of course, `man kill`.

Comment: However, I would keep the default `SIGTERM` signal, which was designed for graceful termination (and is also the signal that the system shutdown sequence would send).

Comment: Upon reflection, I'd agree, `SIGTERM` makes more sense for this. `SIGHUP` is probably more often used for signaling a reload or the like.

Comment: For a threaded app you're better off using `sigmask` and `sigwait` to have control over the thread. This also addresses Basile's concerns.

Comment: Please also note @BasileStarynkevitch answer that complements this one, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8907131/1025411

Answer (score 4):

Unless you modify the target application, I don't see a way.

Consider the following:

```
int main()
{
   MyClass a;
   while ( true )
   {
   }
}
```

You'd have to tell the program to exit the loop. But unless you have some signal handling mechanism on your app, that seems impossible.

You'd need something like:

```
int main()
{
   MyClass a;
   while ( !killSignalReceived() )
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: @LieRyan :)) In my head, true could have been anything, now I see it's redundant.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Zrvan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906773/841108), be aware that only a restricted set of functions can be safely called from a signal handler. The [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page, and the Posix standards, require that only *Async-signal-safe functions* can be called directly or indirectly inside a signal handler. Note that `printf` or `malloc` are not safe inside a signal handler. Signal handler's code is tricky to write (and you cannot debug it easily, because signal sending is non-reproducible).

As the [Glibc](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC358) documentation suggests, your signal handler could just set a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable, which your main loop[s] would test and handle.

You could also decide, if you application is event based, that some socket or named pipe is dedicated to control it. That event loop (perhaps using [select(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) or [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html), or even `pselect` or `ppoll`) could handle the control message on the pipe or socket.

You may be interested by event looping libraries like [libevent](http://libevent.org/). You might also use an HTTP server library like [onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). You could also be interested by SNMP or D-bus.

A trick to overcome the limitation of signal handlers is to have them write on a pipe to the same process, as e.g. [Qt's doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/unix-signals.html) is suggesting. Then the event loop would handle reading on that pipe.

If your application is multi-threaded, signal handling is more tricky. Some signals are delivered to an individual thread.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to handle a signal in the program, and then send that signal using `kill`. In the signal handler, mark a flag that will cause the main loop to end.